# Maximized windows get under the Dock in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, wayland, dock

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 maximized windows are not correctly restored - they get under the Dock when Ubuntu comes back from standby (maybe also after locking screen?).

[image]

If I unmaximize and maximize the window again it correctly autofits without the Dock panel covering the window.

How can this be solved?

Comment: I upgraded to 22.04 right after upgrading to 20.04 and I don't know if this issue was present in 20.04.

Comment: I have this too, no idea how to stop it but I will be watching this post

Comment: Here is the relevant [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1961508)

Comment: Sad to see that this is not resolved 16 months after the initial bug report.

Comment: Is this the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429665/windows-keep-overlapping-with-dock-when-maximized ?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I unintentionally fixed it:

1. I went to Settings/Appearance and enabled the "Auto-hide the Dock" toggle because this Dock problem was bothering me too much
2. then I tested how the feature works by resizing windows from larger to smaller and then back to max
3. I found out that auto-hide is not for me so I disabled the feature and found out that the problem was solved.

Comment: For anyone interested, this did not help the problem in my case (Ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: "Auto-hide the dock" didn't help. But toggling "Panel mode - The dock extends to the screen edge" twice finally did.

Comment: @Mr.Ronald comment should be the accepted answer -- turning Panel Mode off then back on fixed this for me.

Comment: This does not work for me. It resizes all windows so that they fit correctly, but the next time I suspend my computer the bug happens again. I found this workaround that did the trick: https://github.com/popov895/dash-to-dock-workaround

Answer (score 0):

Actually, auto-hide the dock or toggling panel mode, or another option - change panel position from left to right and back, these are all work, but not permanently (at least in my case).

I found solution for me in creating the service which runs the script on startup. This script is watching for screen lock/unlock. When the screen is being locked, it enables the auto-hide option. When the screen is being unlocked, it disables the auto-hide, thus resizing all of the windows. Why auto-hide - I discovered it works better than other two mentioned above options.

1. Create script file:

```
# i.e ~/.local/script/screen_watcher.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | \
( while true
    do read X
    if echo $X | grep "boolean false" &> /dev/null; then
        sleep 0.5
        gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed 'true'
    elif echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then
        gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed 'false'
    fi
    done )
```

2. Allow execution

```
sudo chmod +x ~/.local/script/screen_watcher.sh
```

3. Create service entity file (I did it for user)

```
/home/<user_name>/.config/systemd/user/screen_watcher.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Screen watcher script service
After=default.target
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/<user_name>/.local/script/screen_watcher.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

4. Enable the service. (Note it must be done from user, not root)

```
systemctl --user enable screen_watcher && systemctl --user start screen_watcher
```

5. Check if the service is up and running

```
systemctl --user status screen_watcher.service
```

Hope this helps till annoying overlapping behaviour is fixed.