# Full screen windows hide behind sidebar after suspending

Tags: 22.04, fullscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME 42.9. When I maximize a window it fits nicely next to the sidebar as expected, however if I then suspend the computer and then turn it back on, the full-screened window now sits behind the sidebar. If I just minimize and maximize again, it goes back to normal.

Expected behavior:

[image: expected behavior]

Broken behavior:

[image: broken behavior]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1627
This bug seems to be going for two years now.

Comment: also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1870955

Answer (score 4):

This issue seems to be a long-lasting problem, and doesn't seem to have any temporary fixes for the default settings. However, as suggested by one of the comments in [Maximized windows get under the Dock in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1427116/335738) (specifically, [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427116/maximized-windows-get-under-the-dock-in-ubuntu-22-04#comment2615199_1467413)), one way to prevent this issue from occurring is to switch to disable panel mode. Without panel mode, this issue (at least for me) does not seem to occur anymore.

To do this, go to Settings -> Appearance, and disable panel mode under the **Dock** subsection.

Unfortunately, this will slightly alter the way your side bar looks, but it will fix the issue of your windows hiding underneath it.

Comment: Disabling panel mode did not fix the issue for me. A work around that works for me is making sure everything is minimized before suspending. Someone more savvy than me could figure out a way to automatically minimizing everything when the user hits "Power Off / Log Out -> Suspend"

Answer (score -3):

Good news! It seems to be fixed in the Ubuntu Pro subscription (free for personal use: https://ubuntu.com/pro). The problem disappeared on my machine just after install Ubuntu Pro additional updates.